# Allen Browne's 'ConcatRelated' WHERE argument

Tags: sql, ms-access, concatenation

I have a table containing `serverNames` and `AppID`s in a many-to-many relationship. I want to use [Allen Browne's](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) **ConcatRelated** to have a concatenated list of `AppID`s per `serverName`. I tried:

```
SELECT ServerName, ConcatRelated("AppID", "AppsToServer","ServerName = """ & [ServerName]) & """"
FROM AppsToServer;
```

But it went into a seemingly endless loop of:

> error 3075 - syntax error in string in query expression 'ServerName = "the first server name"'

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: remove extra quotes. Also add second table name

Comment: where are the extra quotes? i was following what the guide (linked in the question) said to do when the foreign key is text? also could you explain why should I add the second table name if all I want to do is concat where serverName = serverName?

Comment: You said I am getting data from two tables. Read this carefully http://allenbrowne.com/casu-17.html

Comment: No, I meant the table has serverNames and AppIDs in it. just the one table :)

Comment: yes, as I realised it was misleading, could you explain where the extra quotes are in my query?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92940/discussion-between-muhammad-muazzam-and-jabbawook).

Answer (score 0):

The code above is correct, the code I had in access was wrong, there was a space in the wrong place so when the function came to compare serverNames it never found a match due to the misleading space.